# Get router link's "active" state to match prop

Tags: vue.js, hyperlink, router

I'm working on a project that uses Vue and vue-router and its routes are deeply nested (ex `2/company/staff/1/timeline`).

Now I reached the `(...) /staff/:id` part and I hit an issue: no matter what value the `id` prop has, all of the route links appear as active. Anybody had that issue before?

P.S: I tried `exact`, not working.

```
<router-link tag="li" :to="{ name: 'business.staff.single', props: {id: 1} }">
  <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('url');"></div>
  <div class="details">User 1</div>
</router-link>

<router-link tag="li" :to="{ name: 'business.staff.single', props: {id: 2} }">
  <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('url');"></div>
  <div class="details">User 2</div>
</router-link>

<router-link tag="li" :to="{ name: 'business.staff.single', props: {id: 3} }">
  <div class="avatar" style="background-image: url('url');"></div>
  <div class="details">User 3</div>
</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I have not worked with `vue-router` lately and now I confused `params` with `props`. Turns out I had to use `params` instead and then it's working by default.